# count down timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

I didnt find some easy java swing tutorial of count down timer in java so I decided to implement it to my own way:

> javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new
>   ClockListener());

```
class ClockListener implements ActionListener {

Integer m = 5;
Integer s = 0;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
if ( (s == 0 ) and ( m == 0 ) ) 
    t.stop() 


    if (s == 0) {
        m--;
        s = 60;
    }
    s--;
    _timeField.setText(m.toString() + ":" + ( (s.toString().length() == 1) ? "0" + s.toString() : s.toString() ) );
}
}
```

_timeField is JTextField

is this correct way how to count down from 5:00 to 0:00 ?

Comment: The SWT timer is not very accurate. To do this without utilizing an external library, you should look at `System.nanoTime()` which will get you much more accurate results.

Comment: @Treebranch: the OP is using the Swing library, not the SWT gui library, but regardless, your statements are correct for Swing as well, although the Swing Timer may be good enough for his purposes.

Comment: To the original poster: I'd give ClockListener a constructor that accepts an long parameter, the number of milliseconds to count down, and initialize m with this rather than hard-code it to 5.

Comment: yea sure this is just first version. I have to paramerized it.. I just need to know if this is accurate to seconds

Comment: Well I really can't see real question here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've implemented it, and it works as expected, that's pretty much the definition of "is it right?" so only you can answer that. There are no massive code style issues here, or anything else, and for the most part you seem to be using Timer as designed.

The question is, "What are you timing?"

#### Precise chemical/sub-atomic interactions, or safety mechanisms for atomic reactors/air traffic control?

The comments under your original question provide a few pointers on alternative implementations or modifications you can make, depending on what you want to do, and how accurate the timer needs to be. If you need sub-second precision, you would really want to start looking into `System.nonoTime()`.

#### Your laundry?

If, on the other hand, you're just building a simple countdown timer (e.g. for cooking, reminding you the laundry is done, etc.) then it really only has to be accurate within 1-5 seconds since what you'll be timing is on the order of minutes/hours, and going over or under a little makes no practical difference. I doubt anyone is really going to notice (or even care) if it's a couple seconds off in these sorts of applications. If this is the case, go with the cleaner/easier to understand implementation.

Comment: hm as I see I have to use system time because I have function when I press space, timer will stop and with this implementation it isnt very exact

Comment: I'm sure you meant to write `System.nanoTime()`